# Change configuration for not change token of private repository

Tags: github

I have a private repository and access of the `raw.githubusercontent.com` by API is using the `?token=AEDIQE3IPAPDAXI6QPVEBALBSAPEU` in the end of the file name. But this `token` change during the time (10 -15 days) and this is not so good for my purposes. I don't find any way to do not change the `token` information. Please, this kind of configuration is possible?

Comment: Which approach did you choose?

Comment: The first, using a `Authorization`, thanks @VonC

Comment: Perfect, well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that token can change, you might consider [creating a Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token), and downloading the files using the `Authorization` header instead of a token in the URL.

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ${PAT}" \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/main/file.txt
```

The other approach [seen here](https://github.community/t/how-to-get-token-of-a-raw-github-file/168635/9) would be, still with a PAT, to

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ${PAT}" \
  https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>/raw/<branch>/<path-to-your-file>
```

> This will return a “redirect (HTTP 302)” with location header value pointing to the URL with the token.

You can get the current "`raw.githubusercontent.com`" token that way.